# How can I check for SSL error inside the pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins build pipeline job having intermittent SSL error which uses conan build package to build. The reason is conan build folder not refreshing cached SSL.

How can I check for SSL error inside the pipeline script so that I can delete the folder if there's SSL error, so that conan would get the fresh certs from config file when retrying the build.

**Update**

Error on jenkins console log is the following:

```
ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conan.bintray.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ping (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

In order to simulate the error, infra admin told that emptying pem cert file would cause this error or entirely removing the cert pem file but the above
error didn't happen but recently again the same issue happened even though below try catch is put in place.
Any idea how to catch the above error and make the retry succeed? I was told deleting the conan folder would refresh teh cert cache but that also seems not happening here
even though at the end admin end up deleting the conan folder manually and after it's started working.

```
def conanDir = "~/.conan"
    def sslError = false
    def retryMaxCount = 5
    def retryCount = 0
try {
    if(!sslError){
        try{
            //try to get conan remotes
            remotes = sh (script: "conan remote list", returnStdout: true)
        } catch (Exception ex){
            sslError = true
            dir(conanDir){
                sh "rm -rf ${conanDir}"
            }
            while(retryCount<retryMaxCount && sslError){
                try {
                    remotes = sh (script: "conan remote list", returnStdout: true)
                    sslError = false
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    sslError = true
                    dir(conanDir){
                        sh "rm -rf ${conanDir}"
                    }
                    retryCount++
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    //some other code here
} catch(Exception RemoteNotFound){
    sh "conan remote add $repo http://server/.../repo"
    sh "conan user -p ${pwd} -r $repo ${usr}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know specifically what conan does when it gets an SSL error, but I assume either it throws an error in Jenkins or it returns a non-zero exit code.

**If it throws a Jenkins error**

You can just wrap this in a `try` step inside a loop:

```
connected = false

while (!connected) {
  try {
    # Connect to conan here
    connected = true
  } catch(Exception exc) {
    println("Connect failed")
}
```

You could also catch the relevant exception instead of putting it in a loop. That's probably better but I don't know what your exception is. If you do use a loop like this, put a maximum number of retries on it.

**If it returns a non-zero exit code**

In this case I guess you're calling it from a `bat` step, in which case I think you can do:

```
bat("conan_connect.bat || exit")
```

EDIT: Edited comment to be clear where the failure was

Comment: I've tried your suggestion as below but the issue happened again.

Error on jenkins console log is the following:
ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conan.bintray.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/ping (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

I've updated my OP since comment has limited characters

Comment: Yeah, the error will still happen but it shouldn't cause the build to halt if it's inside a `try`. You need to do something in the `catch` bit to handle the error and then retry once you've updated your certificates.